# Remotely access my computer's framebuffer console from Android

Tags: linux, console, remote, display

I need to remotely view my computer's display.

I am using programs that I launch from a text console, then they create their own graphical session, like Kodi or EmulationStation (it does not start if X is running). And because they don't use the X server's framebuffer VNC can't capture them.

I tried using VNC (tightvnc and x11vnc), but nearly none of my applications use the X window system.

For the client I want to use an Android device.

Comment: What 'display': X session (graphical, desktop), Shell session (command line)?

Comment: Why do you insist on not using X? I'm not familiar with Kodi and EmulationStation, but as far as I can tell, both can work under X.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using something which uses the framebuffer directly, without using X. It is not possible to display such things remotely.

I don't know this emulationstation thing, but I can say that kodi works just fine with an X server. Also, it has its own android remote app which is a more useful way of controlling it from android; you might want to look at that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using X, what are you using?

For text-only/shell display, ssh is the way to go. For X, you have two options: remote display by changing your display to a network location with an X server, or VNC.

You can also try proprietary solutions, for example TeamViewer, which supports android clients: https://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx

EDIT: There are reports from people that hint that TeamViewer may capture the framebuffer: http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2293900

Comment: It's possible to use graphics on the Linux console too. But this went out of fashion around the same time as years starting with 19.